# text-align doesn't center 2 digit numbers but works on single digits

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I have a circular `div` that contains a number, (there are 12 in total and they increment). I've got the styling all perfect and everything's working nice, but I noticed that if a number has more than one digit `text-align` wont center align the number?

**This is what the single digit div looks like:**

[image]

**This is what the double digit div looks like:**

[image]

As you can see the second image is a few pixles to the right.

Now I realize this can almost definitely be solved by using `padding` instead of `text-align` but I was wondering *why* this happens and *if* there is a work around?

---

**CSS**

```
.number-circle {
    -webkit-border-radius: 999px;
    -moz-border-radius: 999px;
    border-radius: 999px;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
    background-color: #76d17f;
    height: 19px;
    width: 24px;
    border: #fff 3px solid;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:4px;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

*(ignore PIE.htc)*

[**jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/sKpkQ/1/)

Comment: I would bet that it's because the width of the character `1` is not the same as some other characters. Try making it `22` and see if it looks centered. Also, try a mono-spaced font.

Comment: It looks correct in your jsfiddle if you use `22` as @Travesty3 said.

Comment: It seems the text is being centered, but my first thought is equal to Travesty3's.
You could try (for just this div) to try another font like Courier New.

Comment: @Travesty3: Yes that does make sense haha. I just would have thought that it would center any text depending on what width the character has

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the font you're using is not monospaced. Try a monospaced font, like `font-family:courier;`. Take a look at this updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sKpkQ/2/